# How do I properly support the header when expanding a door opening?

Tags: framing, plaster, support

I'm opening up a closet in our 1958 home.

I believe (I plan to get confirmation from a licensed contractor or engineer) that this is not a load bearing wall considering that the opening runs parallel to the joists in the attic above, the wall is an interior wall for a bedroom behind, and considering the way this was installed (both sides of header not resting on a support).

I'd like to remove the left side of the closet opening to get as close to the exterior wall (masonry) as possible.  I plan to keep the 2x4 headers in place just because it will be a whole lot less work for me.  I am wondering if I should install a framing bracket of some sort to provide support to the 2x4 headers that will no longer have the 2x4 vertical support.

[image: Front View of closet opening]

[image: View from inside. If from front this is the left side]

[image: View from inside. If from front this is the right side]

[image: View from inside. If from front this is the left side]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTXBr.jpg): [image: Front View of closet opening 2]

Comment: Don't  "believe."  Get a licenced contractor or carpenter to tell you whether or not it **is** load-bearing.

Comment: Ok...Thanks for your feedback.  I plan to do that.  I've updated my question to reflect that I will get confirmation from a licensed contractor.  My question is aimed at getting assistance with what to do after I get confirmation that this is not a load bearing wall.

Comment: It's probably load bearing so you'd have to scale up the 2x4 header. How much, and how to join everything together, there isn't much anyone here can help you with.

Comment: With no king studs to support the wall I would not call it load bearing, Kings are required in some areas for earthquake safety. There is however a heavy wall there looking at the cement and wire. I would believe the floor of the room behind the wall is the load bearing structure from what I see.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like shoddy remodel work - I'd get a licensed contractor to verify. What you're wanting to open up, may of in fact been previously open, and then sealed up.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see here, and assuming not a load-bearing situation, I'd do this:

- Remove the existing header. You may need to use a recipro saw to cut fasteners behind the plaster on the room side.
- Since you have access from the back side, run a new, full-width double 2x6 header. If you don't have trimmer studs or other support available, fasten the header into the king studs with lag bolts. I'd probably use 3/8" x 4", properly pre-drilled and countersunk.
- Toenail into the pin studs to anchor them to the header.

Optionally use construction adhesive where needed for additional support.